# How do I fix TSC errors when using vite?

Tags: vite, tsc

I am using Vite with a Typescript React project. I have jest tests in my project as well.

When I run `vite build` it seems to be compiling and bundling my test files. I have some stubbed out tests that I plan to get to with some compiling errors right now.

Example when I run `yarn build` which has `tsc && vite build`

```
> yarn build
yarn run v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
$ tsc && vite build
src/core/utils/numberUtils.spec.ts:1:1 - error TS1208: 'numberUtils.spec.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.

1 describe('numberUtils - ', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Looking at it a little more, it's actually Typescript that is throwing the errors when I run `tsc`, though I still am unsure if Vite is bundling it.

**How do I fix `tsc` errors when using vite?**

Comment: Looking at it a little more, it's actually Typescript that is throwing the errors when I run `tsc` , though I still am unsure if Vite is bundling it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 6):

As you noticed, the error is coming from `tsc` and not `vite build`. Vite is not trying to bundle your test files, it is typescript that is trying to typecheck them. Since the `tsc` command fails with errors, `vite build` never even runs.

Typescript lets you ignore files matching a pattern: [How to exclude files ending in '.spec.ts' in tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449107/how-to-exclude-files-ending-in-spec-ts-in-tsconfig-json)

> tsconfig.json
>
> ```json
> "exclude": [
>     "**/*.spec.ts"
> ]
> ```

Comment: This is completely pointless since it's overriden by `include`.